# Angular 2: drawing rectangle on canvas with mouse.

Tags: angular, canvas

I am trying to draw rectangle on the canvas with mouse. Here is my first try:

```
private captureEvents(canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement) {

  Observable
  .fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousedown')
  .subscribe((res: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('MOUSE DOWN');
    const rect = canvasEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.originPoint = new Point();
    this.originPoint.x = res.clientX;
    this.originPoint.y = res.clientY;
    this.startPoint = new Point();
    this.startPoint.x = res.clientX - rect.left;
    this.startPoint.y = res.clientY - rect.top;
  });

  Observable
  .fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseup')
  .subscribe((res: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('MOUSE UP');
    let w: number = res.clientX - this.originPoint.x ;
    let h: number = res.clientY - this.originPoint.y;
    this.cx.rect(this.startPoint.x, this.startPoint.y, w, h);
    this.cx.stroke();
  }
  );
}
```

This works, but it shows rectangle after mouseUp event, and I would like to **see the drawing rectangle when moving the mouse**.

Comment: So is the 'mouse down' string being logged in the console but the rectangle is not being drawn until  'mouse up' is being logged.

Comment: Yes, it is implemented that way. I would like to see the 'progress' of drawing as I am dragging the mouse. But I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Have you tried using the onmousemove event ?

Comment: Well I understand the I have to use some mouse event, but I am not sure how to draw the progress. - Something like clear last rectangle and draw new one.

Comment: On mouse down you can attach a on mouse move event that redraws the canvas as the mouse moves, then you can remove the on mouse move event on mouse up.

Comment: Do u have code for that? I tried context.clearRect(...) but it cleans whole canvas. - As I have a canvas with an image redrawing image every time is bit expensive.

Comment: believe it or not that is the standard canvas way, I have built games with canvas and all sorts. Canvas is pretty damn fast though and it is less expensive then you realise.

Comment: what you should do though is atach an interval to the mouse move event observable and only do a re rewite every 100 miliseconds or so